¿Como solucionar System. ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')?
Acabo de crear una API Net 8 y estoy experimentando un error "System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')" relacionado con la autenticación a la hora de hacer los llamados a los endpoints. Los parametros de launchSettings.json estan correctos y la configuracion en azure sobre los permisos esta correcta. Al principio el error figuraba a la hora de inicial la api, pero esa parte se soluciono acomodando el orden de app.UseAuthentication() app.UseAuthorization().
Detalle del error:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')
   at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName)
   at System.ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(Object argument, String paramName)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI.AzureADB2COpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration.BuildAuthority(AzureADB2COptions AzureADB2COptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2CJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.Configure(String name, JwtBearerOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd[TArg](String name, Func`3 createOptions, TArg factoryArgument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<HandleAsync>g__Handle|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Controller:
using Asp.Versioning;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace api_intercomunicador
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Controlador para accesos sql del intercomunicador
    /// </summary>
    [Authorize]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("api/{version:ApiVersion}/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AdministracionIntercomunicadorController: ControllerBase
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene la lista de acciones de suscripcion
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="urlSuscripcion"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet("AccionesSuscripcionListar")]
        public ActionResult<SuscripcionTipoObjetoAcccion[]> ObtenerAccionesSuscripcion([Required]string urlSuscripcion)
        {
            return AdministracionIntercomunicador.AccionesSuscripcionListar(urlSuscripcion);
        }
}
}

